# Django models unknown column in field list(1054, "unknown column in 'field list'")

Tags: django, django-models

In Django when I try to create a new model called Restaurant from the admin interface I have problem in creating the model object. When I attempt to create a model object from the admin interface:
[image]

I get this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'restaurant_restaurant.addressStreet' in 'field list'")
```

I know that the problem is related to the mySQl data base, but I have no idea of how to resolve this. My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    addressStreet = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Street name of the restaurant', blank = True)
    addressStreetNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text = 'street number', blank = True)
    addressPostCode = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text = '4 digits post code', blank = True)
    addressCity = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text = 'City name', blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text = 'Phone', blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
    cvr = models.CharField(max_length = 50, help_text = 'CVR number', blank = True)

    openingDaysRange1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='For example Monday - Friday', blank = True)
    openingHoursRange1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text = 'For example 14:00 - 20:00', blank = True)

    openingDaysRange2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='For example Saturday - Sunday', blank = True)
    openingHoursRange2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text = 'For example 12:00 - 22:00', blank = True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-name']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from restaurant.models import Restaurant

class RestaurantAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Restaurant
from .forms import RestaurantAdminForm

# Register your models here.
class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RestaurantAdminForm
    
#Registers the product model with the admin interface
admin.site.register(Restaurant, RestaurantAdmin)
```

I have tried to comment out my `Restaurant model` followed by

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

After that remove the comment in my `Restaurant` model and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

It did not resolve the issue. The full error log is:

```
Django version 3.2.12, using settings 'website.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[22/Feb/2022 20:56:46] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10010
Internal Server Error: /admin/restaurant/restaurant/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'restaurant_restaurant.addressStreet' in 'field list'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1815, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'restaurant_restaurant.addressStreet' in 'field list'")
[22/Feb/2022 20:56:48] "GET /admin/restaurant/restaurant/ HTTP/1.1" 500 189401
```

When I manually look up on the table `restaurant_restaurant` content it looks like it was not updated at all! The table I see more resembles an old model that I deleted.

```
DESCRIBE restaurant_restaurant;
+----------------------------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                            | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                               | int               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                             | varchar(50)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address                          | varchar(255)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone                            | varchar(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email                            | varchar(254)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude                         | decimal(20,15)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude                        | decimal(20,15)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active                        | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| has_delivery                     | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_radius                  | int               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_monday_active           | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_monday_timestart        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_monday_timeend          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_tuesday_active          | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_tuesday_timestart       | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_tuesday_timeend         | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_wednesday_active        | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_wednesday_timestart     | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_wednesday_timeend       | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_thursday_active         | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_thursday_timestart      | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_thursday_timeend        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_friday_active           | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_friday_timestart        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_friday_timeend          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_saturday_active         | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_saturday_timestart      | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_saturday_timeend        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_sunday_active           | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_sunday_timestart        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_sunday_timeend          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_monday_active             | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_monday_timestart          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_monday_timeend            | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_tuesday_active            | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_tuesday_timestart         | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_tuesday_timeend           | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_wednesday_active          | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_wednesday_timestart       | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_wednesday_timeend         | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_thursday_active           | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_thursday_timestart        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_thursday_timeend          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_friday_active             | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_friday_timestart          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_friday_timeend            | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_saturday_active           | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_saturday_timestart        | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_saturday_timeend          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_sunday_active             | tinyint(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_sunday_timestart          | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_sunday_timeend            | time(6)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_preparationtime         | smallint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_preparationtime           | smallint          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bagFee                           | smallint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| delivery_fee                     | smallint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| minimum_order_total_for_delivery | smallint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| session_valid_time               | double            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cvr                              | varchar(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
59 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

Comment: I get the error soon as I click on the Restaurant Restaurants link from the admin table. I guess that the table created in sql is restaurants_restaurant. What is it exactly you wanted me to try?

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture. The problem occurs when I click on Restaurants from the admin interface. Also when I click on the add button to add a restaurant object, I can fill in the form, but when I attempt to save the object I get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure it out here still. The thing that looks wrong is the order of the relation. The upper one should be restaurantS and the lower one restaurant, not the other way around.

Comment: Would it be a problem to use the Admin without the form? If not, try doing the admin with only a pass, no code on it. Keeping the register and etc.

Comment: I just changed the admin to class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
    
#Registers the product model with the admin interface
admin.site.register(Restaurant, RestaurantAdmin)

still receiving the same  error. I am on a development platform and in principle I can delete the database and start all over. Will that help?

Comment: If your table is called restaurants_restaurant..., as it should be, no need for migrations, the problem is purely on the admin. I would advise you to stop the process and manage runserver after every major change though.

Comment: I think I found the smoking gun. Have a look on the last part of my question. I went in to the sql data base and checked the table content. When I match the header from that table with my model, it seems that the model was not updated at all! The headers from restaurant_restaurant is the old model not the newest one - although I did python manage.py makemigrations and migrate

Comment: If that is the problem, will it be safe for me to drop the restaurant_restaurant table and then rerun python manage.py makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: The plot thickens! HA, If you don't need the table from before, yes no problem.

Comment: But still, it is very weird that you have the old restaurant model after makemigrations + migrate. I would actually advise to delete all migrations from the restaurants model migrations folder, and start fresh with a new makemigrations, if that is possible.

Comment: I just dropped the tables, but when I attempt to makemigrations and migrate it says that there is nothing to migrate.

Comment: The problem apparently is in the database connection you have(maybe you have more than one possible db to be connected to?). If you have a Restaurant model, without tables in the db, and django is not finding migrations for it, it probably is looking somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think I have been of much help, sorry for that, but I would look for possible multiple databases, or naming conventions (you dropped restaurant_restaurant, is there a restaurants_restaurant though?)

Comment: I ended up dropping the entire database and recreated a new one. Yes there was a database and inside that database was a table called restaurant_restaurant with header from the old model. I think you are right in that I should check the naming conventions. Thanks any way for your help and time in looking into this. I appreciate.